# Java - I have a instance for .get() but it gives error java.lang.NullPointerException at Server.Main.main(Main.java:18)

Tags: java

Here is my Main.java it is around the part after the server socket is made "get().logger().tag();" i have added in the instances all of that i am really unsure as what is wrong with it.

```
public class Main {

    private Logger LOGGER;
    private static Main INSTANCE;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try 
        {
            final int PORT = 43594;
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");
            get().logger().tag(); //This is the part which gives the error 
            get().logger().log("Starting up" + Settings.Settings.NAME + "...");
            //get().init();
            while (true)
            {                                               
                Socket s = server.accept();

                //System.out.println("Client connected from " + s.getLocalAddress().getHostName());

                Client chat = new Client(s);
                Thread t = new Thread(chat);
                t.start();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("An error occured.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Main(int world) {
        this.LOGGER = new Logger();
    }

    public Main init() {
        try {
            long currentTime = Utils.currentTimeMillis();
            logger().log("Completed loading in " + (Utils.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime) + " ms.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger().error("Unable to start server...");
            logger().error(e);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Logger logger() {
        return LOGGER;
    }

    public static Main get() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

i know it is something todo with the get(). but im not sure

Any help would help alot

Thanks,

Comment: You forgot to create a new instance of Main.

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning `INSTANCE` anywhere, and seeing as it's `private`, I'm guessing it's also `null`.

Assign `INSTANCE = new World(...)`.

Comment: INSTANCE = new World(Integer.parseInt(args[0])); //would it be like this? im not quite sure what to put inside the brackets

Comment: I don't know, is `args[0]` what you want? Test it?

Comment: public static void main1(String[] args) {
   Settings.Settings.DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[1]);
   INSTANCE = new Main(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
 }//im not quite sure what todo with it tbh ive added these args